# Template Parse Warnings in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack-2, typescript2.1

After updating the packages to latest version. While Running the Application in browser i am facing the warning message in console:

```
Template parse warnings:
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("[WARNING ->]<template><div class="mat-autocomplete-panel" role="listbox" [id]="id" [ngClass]="_getClassList()" #p"): ng:///MdAutocompleteModule/MdAutocomplete.html@0:0
```

Comment: The error message tells it all. What't the problem?

Comment: I am not using template tag in my app

Comment: Perhaps not directly. You might use components that do.

Comment: Under Components i am using templateUrl only

Comment: `templateUrl` is not related at all. What about `MdAutocompleteModule`?

Comment: I have not used MdAutocompleteModule

Comment: I can't imagine the error message coming out of nowhere. So you don't use any 3rd-party components at all?

Comment: What if you remove `"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",` and `"angular2-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-flex": "^1.0.3"` from your config?

Comment: I am using 3rd-party components like primeface-datatable and i am not using template

Comment: i will check and let you know

Comment: As I said, then probably one of these 3rd-party components is using `<template>`. Either live with the warning until versions become available that are updated for Angular4 or remove the components from your project.

Comment: Yes it worked fine after removing the 3rd-party  packages from config. Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Angular used the `<template>` tag prevented for example using Polymer with Angular, therefore they changed Angular to use `<ng-template>` instead, to free `<template>` for "normal" usage.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11994